# Relative lift of an experiment - Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am trying to calculate the relative lift of an experiment in tableau however I am getting an error everytime of this:

[Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver]Teradata DatabaseThe format or data contains a bad character.
SELECT SUM(CAST(CAST(CAST((CASE WHEN ("tableau_input_final"."experiment_group" = 'Control') THEN 'control_cust' ELSE NULL END) AS DOUBLE PRECISION) AS BIGINT) AS BIGINT)) AS "temp(calculation_7656119953348", SUM(CAST((CASE WHEN ("tableau_input_final"."experiment_group" = 'Control') THEN "tableau_input_final"."nbr_logins_anyday" ELSE NULL END) AS BIGINT)) AS "temp(calculation_7656119953341", SUM(CAST((CASE WHEN ("tableau_input_final"."experiment_group" = 'Treatment1') THEN "tableau_input_final"."nbr_logins_anyday" ELSE NULL END) AS BIGINT)) AS "temp(treatment conversion rate", SUM(CAST(CAST(CAST((CASE WHEN ("tableau_input_final"."experiment_group" = 'Treatment1') THEN 'treatment_cust' ELSE NULL END) AS DOUBLE PRECISION) AS BIGINT) AS BIGINT)) AS "temp(treatment conversion rat1" FROM "pp_scratch"."tableau_input_final" "tableau_input_final" GROUP BY ()

The way I have done it is that I have I have the control conversion rate and treatment as a conversion rate as calculated fields and then calculating relative lift is calculated as

```
if [Control Conversion Rate]>0
then ([Treatment Conversion Rate (copy)]-[Control Conversion Rate])/[Control Conversion Rate]
elseif [Control Conversion Rate]=0
then 0
end
```

Can you please guide me as to why am I getting such an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Teradata returns

> [Teradata][ODBC Teradata Driver] The format or data contains a bad character

The data you are trying to calculate is not formatted correctly. The casting of datatype could be done in a separate calculated field or change the type of data format outside of the Tableau calculated field.

This error comes back if the output you are trying to convert has rogue characters so when you attempt converting to those integer formats it will come back with an error. Check for Nulls, NaN or similar.